# Scheme quote procedure

Tags: scheme, echo, quote

Exercise question:

> The arguments passed to a procedure need not always be of the same type. Define a procedure echo that accepts any kind of value and returns that value.

I currently made:

```
(define echo
  (lambda (x)
     (quote x)))
```

but the problem is that the procedure won't it will print x, if I type a number or a value.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you think you need `quote`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're being asked to implement the [identity function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function). If your interpreter provides it, the `echo` procedure could be implemented as an alias:

```
(define echo identity)
```

Or as an alias for `values` in Racket:

```
(define echo values)
```

If not, it's very simple to implement `echo` from scratch: just return what was passed as a parameter, there's no need to use `quote` for that:

```
(define (echo x) x)
```

Or using explicitly a `lambda`:

```
(define echo (lambda (x) x))
```

All of the above procedures will accept any kind of value and return that value, for example:

```
(echo "hello")
> "hello"
(echo 42)
> 42
(echo (quote x))
> 'x
```

Answer (score 2):

(quote x) prevents evaluation of the symbol x, so the returned value is NOT the value of x
but the symbol itself.

the identity function takes an arguments and returns it:

```
(lambda (x) x)
```

when applied:

```
((lambda (x) x) 4)
;=> 4

((lambda (x) (quote x)) 4)
;=> x
```